# React router with multi form steppers

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to attach react router with steppers? so that when the user clicks next button it also changes the react router url. for example from "mainForm" to "mainForm/contact

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with an anchor in your next button

```
<a href="/mainForm/contact" />
```

And react router will do the rest of the job.

If you want to use `<Link />` here is an example:

```
<Link to={"/step" + numberStep}>
  <Button renderAs="button">
    <span>Login</span>
  </Button>
</Link>
```

Comment: can I use <Link to="/mainForm/contact/" ><button>Next</button></Link> instead of an anchor tag? will it work?

Comment: saveAndContinue = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep(1)(2);
  }

Comment: <MDBBtn size="sm" style={{ color: 'white-text' }} className="button rounded success-color"  onClick={this.saveAndContinue }

Comment: So my next button calls a function to change the stepper

Comment: I would need to see all of your code to help you in that case.

Comment: please have a look at this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-engelbart-los00?file=/src/App.js

Comment: the components are empty

Comment: That's weird, please try this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-engelbart-los00?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217816/discussion-between-paul-and-martin-gainza-koulaksezian).